# Object parameter in class-validator registerDecorator function

Tags: nestjs, class-validator

I am trying to understand the object parameter in the following decorator function

```js
import { registerDecorator, ValidationOptions, ValidationArguments} from 'class-validator';

export function IsLongerThan(
  property: string,
  validationOptions?: ValidationOptions
) {
  return function (object: Object, propertyName: string) {
    registerDecorator({
      name: 'isLongerThan',
      target: object.constructor,
      propertyName,
      constraints: [property],
      options: validationOptions,
      validator: {
        validate(value: any, args: ValidationArguments) {
          const [relatedPropertyName] = args.constraints;
          const relatedValue = (args.object as any)[relatedPropertyName];
          return (
            typeof value === 'string' &&
            typeof relatedValue === 'string' &&
            value.length > relatedValue.length
          );
        },
      },
    });
  };
}
```

Would someone help me understand the object parameter in the return function,

```js
return function (object: Object, propertyName: string) {
```

what it means and how do I pass it in?

Thank you!

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html

Comment: Thank you @MicaelLevi - I will have to do some reading.